# Keyboard layout switch troubles after 16.04.1 upgrade

Tags: lubuntu, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, lxde, capslock

I recently updated from 14.04.4 to 16.04.1. I expected there will be some problems (and there were), but the one I wasn't able to solve so far is keyboard layout switcher behaves wrong.

I use Gnome fallback at home and LXDE at work, and used to switch layouts by CapsLock. In Gnome Fallback it doesn't work anymore, I can't set the switcher key to CapsLock, instead it shows New acceleration... and when I press Capslock - it strangely replaces it with 'NextGroup'. But at least Ctrl+Shift works.

On LXDE problems are different - Keyboard layout handler (which uses setxkbmap, as I understood) seems to work, but not always. Sometimes, I can switch layout, sometimes, it reacts neither on CapsLock, nor on any other keyboard combination, and I need to switch between windows, until I'm able to switch it again.

Comment: sorry for being not so specific, but would be happy to provide as much info as related.